# Excel 2013 issue when trying to import file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I downloaded a file to work on in excel. The file is supposed to consist of 3 different columns of data, but when I open the file in excel all 3 columns of data are loaded into a single columns. How do I separate the data into 3 different columns?

This is what my spreadsheet looks like when I load the file into excel:

```
CustomerID,Quantity,UnitPrice
17850,2,7.65
17850,6,2.55
17850,6,3.39
17850,6,3.39
17850,6,3.39
17850,6,4.25
17850,8,2.75
17850,6,1.85
17850,6,1.85
```

However customerid, quantity, and unitprice are supposed to be their own independent columns. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a csv (comma separated values) file, to convert it do:

- select the data
- go to data - text to columns
- select "delimited" and click next
- mark "comma" as delimiter, then click finish

[image]